# Initialization of tabs in tabControl

Tags: c#, user-controls, initialization, tabcontrol

I'm using tabControl with many tabs(>10), and each tab has UserContol. But tabs Initialize each control at starting my app. It's making my program too slow. I want to run my userControl only when I click on it. How can I do this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should improve your UserControls that they do not do the performance stuff until they get activated/visible. Give them a method `Activate` which the tabcontrol calls when the tabs becomes the selected tab.

Alternatively you could not add the UserControls to the TabPage content in the designer. Instead create your UserControl when the tab becomes active. But this will make them insivible in the Designer.

Answer (score 0):

You could either have a marker such as `IsLoaded` and until a tab is selected, not load the controls. When the tab is then selected, if it hasn't already been loaded, you could load the controls and add them at runtime to the tabs `Controls`.

Or, you could have the controls added but not do anything with them until the tab is selected, and then each tab will do the calculations or whatever and update the correct controls.

It's all about your design.

Answer (score 0):

Add a handler to your UserControl's `Load` event. Then kick off slow activity in the handler.